# Kotlin - Random numbers without repeating

Tags: kotlin, sorting, random

I have a question, how to prevent random numbers from being repeated.
By the way, can someone explain to me how to sort these random numbers?

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttom)


    button.setOnClickListener {

        var liczba = List(6){Random.nextInt(1,69)}
        textView.text = liczba.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call `sorted` on a list to get a sorted version (or `sort` on a ``MutableList`` if you want to sort it in place)

Comment: you can also create a MutableList to add every new Rwandan number and the compare that the newly generated random is not in your generated list. If it does, you drop is can call random again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html) are a great way to generate streams of data and limit or filter the results.

```kotlin
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

val randomInts = generateSequence {
  // this lambda is the source of the sequence's values
  Random.nextInt(1..69)
}
  // make the values distinct, so there's no repeated ints
  .distinct()
  // only fetch 6 values
  // Note: It's very important that the source lambda can provide
  //       this many distinct values! If not, the stream will
  //       hang, endlessly waiting for more unique values.
  .take(6)
  // sort the values
  .sorted()
  // and collect them into a Set
  .toSet()
```

[*run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/zvs6JFeCj)

To make sure this works, here's a property-based-test using [Kotest](https://kotest.io/docs/proptest/property-based-testing.html).

```kotlin
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FunSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.collections.shouldBeMonotonicallyIncreasing
import io.kotest.matchers.collections.shouldBeUnique
import io.kotest.matchers.collections.shouldHaveSize
import io.kotest.property.Arb
import io.kotest.property.arbitrary.positiveInts
import io.kotest.property.checkAll
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt


class RandomImageLogicTest : FunSpec({

  test("expect sequence of random ints is distinct, sorted, and the correct size") {
    checkAll(Arb.positiveInts(30)) { limit ->

      val randomInts = generateSequence { Random.nextInt(1..69) }
        .distinct()
        .take(limit)
        .sorted()
        .toSet()

      randomInts.shouldBeMonotonicallyIncreasing()
      randomInts.shouldBeUnique()
      randomInts.shouldHaveSize(limit)
    }
  }

})
```

The test passes!

```
Test                                      Duration  Result
expect sequence of random ints is di...   0.163s    passed
```

Answer (score 8):

There are three basic methods to avoid repeating 'random' numbers. If they don't repeat then they are not really random of course.

- with a small range of numbers, randomly shuffle the numbers and pick them in order after the shuffle.
- with a medium size range of numbers, record the numbers you have picked, and reject any repeats.  This will get slow if you pick a large percentage of the numbers available.
- with a very large range of numbers you need something like an encryption: a one-to-one mapping which maps 0, 1, 2, 3 ... to the numbers in the (large) range.  For example a 128 bit encryption will give an apparently random ordering of non-repeating 128-bit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
val size = 6
val s = HashSet<Int>(size)
while (s.size < size) {
    s += Random.nextInt(1,69)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I create simple class, in constructor you enter "from" number (minimal possible number) and "to" (maximal posible number), class create list of numbers.
"nextInt()" return random item from collection and remove it.

```
class RandomUnrepeated(from: Int, to: Int) {
    private val numbers = (from..to).toMutableList()
    fun nextInt(): Int {
        val index = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(numbers.size)
        val number = numbers[index]
        numbers.removeAt(index)
        return number
    }
}
```

usage:

```
val r = RandomUnrepeated(0,100)
r.nextInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @IR42's answer, you can do something like this

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun getUniqueRandoms() = sequence {
    val seen = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    while(true) {
        val next = Random.nextInt()
        // add returns true if it wasn't already in the set - i.e. it's not a duplicate
        if (seen.add(next)) yield(next)
    }
}

fun main() {
    getUniqueRandoms().take(6).sorted().forEach(::println)
}
```

So `getUniqueRandoms` creates an independent sequence, and holds its own internal state of which numbers it's produced. For the caller, it's just a basic sequence that produces unique values, and you can consume those however you like.

Like @rossum says, this really depends on how many you're going to produce - if you're generating a lot, or this sequence is really long-lived, that set of seen numbers will get very large over time. Plus it will start to slow down as you get more and more collisions, and have to keep trying to find one that hasn't been seen yet.

But for most situations, this kind of thing is just fine - you'd probably want to benchmark it if you're producing, say, millions of numbers, but for something like 6 it's not even worth worrying about!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Set and MutableSet instead of List:

```
val mySet = mutableSetOf<Int>() 
while (mySet.size < 6) 
   mySet.add(Random.nextInt(1, 69))
```

Comment: The question asked for non-repeating numbers, but the code in this answer might generate repeats.

Comment: From Kotlin Reference: Random(seed: Long) returns a repeatable random number generator seeded with the given seed value. Two generators with the same seed produce the same sequence of values within the same version of Kotlin runtime.

Comment: So it means if you give a different seed number it can generate different numbers. Getting current time in Milli seconds can be a good example of different seed numbers in various parts of the code.

Comment: OP asked for non-repeating numbers. If a Random is seeded, then it still can still produce duplicates. For example, given `val rand = Random(1668699672475)`, the first 5 numbers of `List(6) { rand.nextInt(1, 69) }` will be 54, repeated. [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/8S_Dbo6rk).

Comment: Of course with the same seed you will get the same sequence of repeating numbers.  That's why they added seed, so you if set a different seed number each time (like current time in millis) you wouldn't get the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: This can solve his problem: List(6) { Random(Clock.System.now().toEpochMilliseconds()).nextInt(1, 69) }

Comment: You're proposing using multiple Random instances. When I [run your proposed code](https://pl.kotl.in/Dtxmntqxa) it generates multiple duplicates, e.g. `[12, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31]`. I don't understand why using different Random instances would mean the values each instance generates would be unique. Also, setting a seed manually, based on time, isn't necessary: Randoms are given different seeds by default (with [one important exception](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52618) if you're on Android!).

Comment: You are right, forget about the last code this should solve the problem: val rand = Random(Clock.System.now().toEpochMilliseconds()) and then List(6) { rand.nextInt(1, 69) }

Comment: Five 31 happened because it ran very fast and should have been executed in the same milliseconds and so the same seed for the last 5 numbers, but the last one should have a different sequence in each run. BTW, I have tried the last one in Playground and it's working now

Comment: No... It doesn't _always_ work. I [re-ran your proposal](https://pl.kotl.in/RINd-XViA) And when the system time was `1668771106465` it generated `[17, 17, 4, 62, 27, 36]` - which contains 17 twice. Any instance of a Random might generate duplicate values. (It doesn't matter if it has a seed! Or if the seed is set using the system time!)

Comment: Oh you mean in the list, so you can use Set instead of List:
    val mySet = mutableSetOf<Int>();
    val rand = Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    while (mySet.size < 6)
     mySet.add(rand.nextInt(1, 69))